# List of deleted items from using Delete

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

```
partstodelete = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}.. {2, 21}, {2, 28}, {2, 35}..};
```

`Delete[data, partstodelete]` deletes parts `partstodelete` from `data`.

How do I just get a list of the parts (i.e what is deleted; or the complement of `data` and `Delete[data, partstodelete]`).

Seems like it should be straightforward using `Part`, but `data[[partstodelete]]` does not work (`Part` doesn't seem to allow depth of part specifications if giving it a list?)

Comment: Have you tried [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) or [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html)?

Answer (score 4):

```
data = Array[a, {3, 10}];

partstodelete = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 8}};

data2 = Delete[data, partstodelete];
```

Using [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), the values deleted are

```
data[[##]] & @@@ partstodelete

(* {a[1, 2], a[1, 5], a[1, 6], a[2, 3], a[2, 5], a[2, 8]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that returns (similar to [`TakeDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeDrop%60.html)) both the kept and the deleted parts of input list using [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) + [`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) + [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html):

```
ClearAll[deleteExtract]
deleteExtract = Through[{ Delete, Extract} @ ##] &;

data = Array[a, {3, 7}];
partstodelete = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}};

MapAt[Framed, data, partstodelete] // TableForm
```

[image]

```
{kept, deleted} = deleteExtract[data, partstodelete];

kept
```

> ```
>  {{a[1, 1], a[1, 3], a[1, 4], a[1, 7]}, 
>   {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 4], a[2, 6], a[2, 7]}, 
>   {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3], a[3, 4], a[3, 5], a[3, 6], a[3, 7]}}
> ```

```
deleted
```

> ```
> {a[1, 2], a[1, 5], a[1, 6], a[2, 3], a[2, 5]}
> ```

```
data /. { x : Alternatives @@ (Join @@ kept) :> Highlighted[x], 
   x : Alternatives @@ deleted :>  Highlighted[x, Background -> Pink]} // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0},
   {3, 4, 1},
   {9, 2, 4, 6}};

pos = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}};

del = Delete[pos] @ list
```

{{7, 9, 1, 6, 0}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}}

Using `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1) to get the deleted elements

```
MapThread[DeleteElements, {list, del}]
```

{{8, 2, 3}, {1}, {9, 4}}

Difference to some earlier answers and comments:

`Extract` flattens

```
Extract[pos] @ list
```

{8, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4}

So does Bob Hanlon's answer

```
list[[##]] & @@@ pos
```

{8, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4}

`Complement` sorts

```
MapThread[Complement, {list, del}]
```

{{2, 3, 8}, {1}, {4, 9}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0}, {3, 4, 1}, {9, 2, 4, 6}};

pos = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `MapThread`, `DeleteCases` and `ReplacePart`:

```
del = ReplacePart[list, pos -> Nothing]

(*{{7, 9, 1, 6, 0}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}}*)

MapThread[DeleteCases[#1, Alternatives @@ #2] &, {list, del}]

(*{{8, 2, 3}, {1}, {9, 4}}*)
```